# Random caps-lock when writing messages using React Native TextInput

Tags: react-native, textinput

Random caps-lock when writing messages in React Native TextInput

react-native: 0.55.4

We use React Native TextInput to allow the user to enter data. Recently, when writing messages, the text input has been acting like crazy and switching between caps and non-caps characters at totally random times when writing.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

One of the workarounds we have used is to set autoCapitalize="none" and that seems to have reduced the random caps lock but it does have the expected side effect of none of the capitalization working when you would usually expect it to work (after a full stop etc.)

Below is the text input that is causing this issue:

```
  <TextInput
  style={this.getTextInputStyle()}
  multiline={true}
  numberOfLines={4}
  onChangeText={text => {
    this.setState({
      text: text
    });
  }}
  value={this.state.text}
  placeholder={"Type your text here..."}
  placeholderTextColor="#2dc4ad"
  autoCapitalize="none"
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
    //Some code here
  }}
  onSelectionChange={(event) => {
    //Some code here
  }}
/>
```

Comment: can you provide code? how do you declare text input together with its onchange?

Comment: @AnnieHill - Thank you for your response. I have updated my question with the text input showing the onChange event handler. Any assistance from you would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We've seen the same thing on 0.55.4 also, we shall be investigating tomorrow. Did you have any luck finding a better fix?

Comment: We've seen the same thing on 0.55.4 also, we shall be investigating tomorrow. Did you have any luck finding a better fix?

Comment: We've seen the same thing on 0.55.4 also, we shall be investigating tomorrow. Did you have any luck finding a better fix?

Comment: Hi, we've seen the same thing on 0.55.4 also, we shall be investigating tomorrow. Did you have any luck finding a better fix?

Comment: @LukeRhodes - When we upgraded to React Native version 0.57.8, the problem went away.